# JavaFX does not seem to work with Java from IntellJ and MS/VS code. Imports not found

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, javafx, visual-studio-code

I can't seem to get javaFX working on my system. I need it for a school project.

I've done some research into this matter and concluded the following :

Current JDK versions do not standardly include javaFX anymore. 
So I need to download and install it manually. 
I came across this website : https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction
which instructs me to install Java11 OpenJDK which I believe includes JavaFX.

I've downloaded the macOS version from this link : http://jdk.java.net/11/
Unzipped it. and copied it manually to this location : "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ (the folder itself is called jdk-11.0.2.jdk

The openjfx website instructed me next to set the HOME environment variable. And it included a tutorial on how to do that. I've then successfully changed my JAVA_HOME variable as instructed. 
(tutorial link : https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux)

My java version now looks similar to the one on the openjfx website
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG1ik.png)

The website then instructs to download a appropriate JavaFX runtime from this source : https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
It says to download and extract that file to a "desired" location. Which I would assume would be this : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
So I moved the extracted openjfx-11_osx-x64_bin-sdk.zip to that location. 
Finally it instructs me to add the following environment variable :
export PATH_TO_FX=path/to/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib

To, I assume, my bash profile so I did that. I substituted the path/to/ part with the actual path. Which would be :  export PATH_TO_FX=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk1.3/lib

(the zip indeed containts a lib folder with javafx.jar files)

At this point this is how my bash profile looks : 
[Bash profile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jows.jpg)

So basically the openjfx site now says I should be okay to run javafx 11 applications from the command line. With a specified command.

So with this long command 
*javac --module-path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFx.java*

I am able to successfully run a java file which imports javaFx. 
But this is so cumbersome.

I suspect I should do something with setting my environment/path variables so that I can use JavaFX from within IntelliJ or preferably in MS visual studio code.

Does anyone know a concise and straightforward way to configure my system so that I can just use Java and JavaFX from Vistual Studio Code or IntellJ

Comment: I'm on MacOS Mojave 10.14.

Comment: For information on using JavaFX 11 with the major Java IDEs (not Visual Studio Code) combined with Gradle, Maven, or no build tool, see [Getting Started with JavaFX 11](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this whole process by switching to Maven based projects.
A maven project has all build and dependency information in a file called `pom.xml` and will simplify all other dependency issues.

The steps are detailed on [Getting started with JavaFX 11 with maven](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven)
The steps for Intellij are also detailed [on the same site](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij) but they are somewhat complicated. 
 Netbeans 10 can open any maven project as a native project so I will detail steps for it.

Create a new project > Maven > Java Application
In project tab > Project files open `pom.xml`. Add the following lines under `project` tag.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
  <version>11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
  <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

Above snippet was taken from [HelloFX github source](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/HelloFX/Maven/hellofx). You can download that repo and open the folder in Netbeans 10 and you'll have full project capabilities.

Comment: I've looked into a Maven project with IntellJ. I used a pom.xml for javaFx and It seems to work flawless now. Many thanks!